# Heroku Review App URL just leads to a 404

Tags: heroku

I am trying to incorporate review apps to our delivery workflow and i just finished getting everything set up and i created a pull request to test.

Heroku successfully created the app

[image]

But when i click to view the app, it returns the standard heroku 404 page

[image]

Is there anything i need to modify in order to view my app? Do i need to add a URL?

My current staging app has a domain assigned to it since we use subdomains like `app.domain.com` and `api.domain.com` i am not sure if this could be the reason.

EDIT: I believe that my issue does have to do with my app being on a subdomain, all paths are either at `www.domain.com` or `app.domain.com` does this mean i cannot use the review app feature on Heroku?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like since i use subdomains for my app i cannot access it VIA a heroku app url. In order for me to use a review app i would need to set a dedicated URL every time.

The only workaround seems to be (from Heroku support):

> You could perhaps use a post deploy script to script something using the API - https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/github-integration-review-apps#the-postdeploy-script

This isn't a really good workaround but its an option.